# Where did the other parts of coccoliths go, if not in chalk?

Tags: carbonate, chalk

It took a lot of algae shells to make a chalk deposit, and one finds fossils of bigger organisms in them, and the flints/cherts where silicates ?condensed? during lithification. But where did the non-shell parts of the coccoliths go? Did currents separate the calcite from the organics? If they decomposed in place, didn't that leave the organic carbon of the decomposers? Was it fluid enough to squeeze out during lithification? Is this happening somewhere currently?

Comment: to answer this you only need to visit a beach,and find empty shells from snails and mussels,the animal dies and rot/gets eaten before the shell can break down.